# Use SQLite in windows phone silverlight 8.1

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to use sqlite in a windows phone silverlight 8.1 project. I installed the sqlite for windows phone 8.1 (the .vsix file) but I couldn't find the reference?

Comment: Have you watched this video http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/19? It shows in details how to use it, including the Silverlight version.

Comment: Yes I did, it was recorded one month ago and they have said that at that time there was no build yet for silverlight 8.1 and they were working on it but I don't know if they have completed this task

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b)

Note that:
This is a pre-release version for beta testing use only.  This is not a release.

Comment: Thanks. How can we know when the release version will be available. And can we work with tis pre-release version

Comment: I would imagine the release will be soon but don't know for sure.  I've been using the pre-release.  I think this version is the same as the SQLite for Windows Runtime release.